# Вылетает при открытии нового Activity (android studio kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, activity, android-intent

Начал заниматься по видео-урокам и возникла проблема по одному из них с вылетом программы в эмуляторе и на телефоне при нажатии на кнопку, которая запускает новое Activity.
Сам урок вот: https://neco-desarrollo.es/2021/04/%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-18-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0

Сразу скажу, что прочитал все комменты к видео, такие проблемы возникали, но решение никто не написал.

Код активити которое пытаюсь запустить:

```
package com.example.practic

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.practic.constance.Constance
import com.example.practic.databinding.ActivitySignInUpBinding


class SignInUpActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var bindingClass: ActivitySignInUpBinding
    var signState = "empty"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        bindingClass = ActivitySignInUpBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(bindingClass.root)

        signState = intent.getStringExtra(Constance.SIGN_STATE)!!
        if (signState == Constance.SIGN_IN_STATE){
            bindingClass.edName.visibility = View.GONE
            bindingClass.edName2.visibility = View.GONE
            bindingClass.edName3.visibility = View.GONE
            bindingClass.imAvatar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

        }
    }

    fun onClickDone(view: View){
        if (signState == Constance.SIGN_IN_STATE){
    }
        }

    fun onClickAvatar(view: View){
        bindingClass.imAvatar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

}
```

Код активити из которого запускаю:

```
package com.example.practic

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import com.example.practic.constance.Constance
import com.example.practic.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.practic.databinding.ActivitySignInUpBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var bindingClass : ActivityMainBinding
    private var login: String = "empty"
    private var password: String = "empty"
    private var name: String = "empty"
    private var name2: String = "empty"
    private var name3: String = "empty"
    private var avatarImId: Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(s: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(s)
        bindingClass = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(bindingClass.root)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == Constance.REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN){

        }
        else if (requestCode == Constance.REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_UP){

        }
    }

    fun onClickSignIn (view: View){
        val intent = Intent(this,ActivitySignInUpBinding ::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(Constance.SIGN_STATE, Constance.REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN)
        startActivityForResult(intent, Constance.REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN)
    }
    fun onClickSignUp (view: View){
        val intent = Intent(this,ActivitySignInUpBinding ::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(Constance.SIGN_STATE, Constance.REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_UP)
        startActivityForResult(intent, Constance.REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_UP)
        }

}
```

В манифесте новое активити добавил:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.practic">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Practic">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SignInUpActivity"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Такие ошибки выдает в logcat:

```
2022-05-10 00:07:09.044 3574-3600/com.example.practic E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
2022-05-10 00:07:15.681 3574-3574/com.example.practic E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.practic, PID: 3574
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:446)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:441)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.practic/com.example.practic.databinding.ActivitySignInUpBinding}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2005)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1673)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4586)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:597)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4544)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:583)
        at com.example.practic.MainActivity.onClickSignIn(MainActivity.kt:39)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:441) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2022-05-10 00:07:31.148 3657-3687/com.example.practic E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
```

В чем может быть причина и как это исправить?

Добавил активити в манифест, исправил слушатель нажатий, но теперь выходят следующие ошибки:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.practic.SignInUpActivity.onCreate(SignInUpActivity.kt:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8031)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3608)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Проблема в строке signState = intent.getStringExtra(Constance.SIGN_STATE)!!
При ее удалении активити запускается, но без нужного редактирования.

Comment: ваша причина это `Could not execute method for android:onClick`

Comment: Вылетает при нажатии кнопки - до вызова активити даже не доходит. Много кода, но нет главного - разметки с кнопкой

Comment: попробуйте читать не комменты к видео, а специально написанную литературу. Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException

Comment: Так вы же запускаете по нажатию на кнопку совсем не то, что в уроке указано.

Comment: Мне кажется проблема в строчке 
'signState = intent.getStringExtra(Constance.SIGN_STATE)!!'
Если я в манифесте ставлю приоритет на запуск второго активити и удаляю в нем эту строчку, то запуск происходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка здесь:

```
val intent = Intent(this,ActivitySignInUpBinding::class.java)
```

нужно передать класс Активити а не байндинга:

```
val intent = Intent(this, ActivitySignInUp::class.java)
```

Об этом запись в логе:

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.practic/com.example.practic.databinding.ActivitySignInUpBinding}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Вторая ошибка из-за подобной записи:

```
signState = intent.getStringExtra(Constance.SIGN_STATE)!!
```

Ставить подобный оператор (гарантия не нуль-значения) там где он в принципе возможен - очень плохая практика.
Так лучше:

```
signState = intent.getStringExtra(Constance.SIGN_STATE) ?: "empty"
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробное разъяснение, поправил оба момента, теперь активити запускается, но не применяются условия из-под if для запуска активити (часть полей должна сворачиваться) 
       
 signState = intent.getStringExtra(Constance.SIGN_STATE) ?: "empty"


        if (signState == Constance.SIGN_IN_STATE){

            bindingClass.edName.visibility = View.GONE
            bindingClass.edName2.visibility = View.GONE
            bindingClass.edName3.visibility = View.GONE
            bindingClass.imAvatar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

Comment: Это потому что при создании интента: intent.putExtra(Constance.SIGN_STATE, Constance.REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN) - для ключа "Constance.SIGN_STATE" передается значение "Constance.REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN". А там где условие if - берется значение для ключа "Constance.SIGN_STATE", которое должно по логике быть "Constance.REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN", но сравнивается с "Constance.SIGN_IN_STATE" - по этому блок и не выполняется.

Comment: Просто facepalm самому себе за невнимательность... Спасибо большое!